# Read specific page from pdf document and display pdf page to specific user

Tags: display, pdf, website, user

Every month I have pdf file with 40 pages, and I upload file to folder on webserver. Every user on internal company website have his own page in that pdf file. How to display specific page to specific user, without manual embedding to user profile page? Or display it on designated page for that pdf file, but with selection for user to pick his own page from pdf?

Better option would be that user can navigate whole archive of pdf and pick year, month and his page from pdf.
User's page in pdf has always same page number and his own phone number becouse pdf is phone bill for company mobile phones.

Comment: So are you not wanting the other employees to see the other numbers? and wanting to display the page of the employee to make it easier to document or for the user to look over the bill?

Comment: It would be good to restrict users from seeing other users bill but not mandatory. I want user to see the bill, and print the bill if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the page number you can add #page=PageNum to the end of the URL.

For example:

https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf#page=4

Take a look at https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html for more info.